# Convert JAXBElement<XMLGregorianCalendar> to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, xmlgregoriancalendar

I am trying to convert the JAXBElement-XMLGregorianCalendar to offsetDateTime. I am able to do that but i want to convert the date in a particular format.

Code i am using to convert :  calendarValue is 2016-03-25T00:00:00+05:30 but i need to covert the type to offsetDateTime so i am doing below conversion

```html
calendarValue.toGregorianCalendar().getTime().toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

In response i am getting the value after converting as : 2016-03-24T18:30:00Z while i want the converted value as : 2016-03-25T00:00:00+05:30.

Could anyone pls help to get the desired conversion of dateTime.

Comment: Are you conflating text formats with date-time objects? Only textual strings have a “format”. Date-time objects can parse strings as inputs, and generate strings as outputs, but such strings are always distinct and separate from the date-time objects.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
myXMLGregorianCalendar
.toGregorianCalendar()
.toZonedDateTime()
.format( 
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME 
)
```

## Details

Convert an `XMLGregorianCalendar` legacy object to another legacy class, `GregorianCalendar` as an intermediate step.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = myXMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar() ;
```

Convert to the modern class.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

This `ZonedDateTime` object may meet your needs.

Generate a string representing the value of this moment in your desired format, though your format unfortunately masks the name of the time zone which is valuable information.

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME ) ;
```

But if you want to see that same moment adjusted to UTC, just extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

If you need the more flexible `OffsetDateTime` class, apply an offset.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```